# How to create the slider move when scrolling the page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

The slider should scroll along with the page.
I create a slider, it scrolls, but the page does not move.
And must also move with the slider.
How can you make such a slider, please help.

an example of finished work is --> https://chulakov.ru/company

`` class ReviewSlider extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        reviews: [
            {
               .........
            }
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    let slickListDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('slick-list')[0]
    slickListDiv.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.deltaY > 0 ? this.slider.slickNext() : this.slider.slickPrev()
    })
}

render() {
    const settings = {
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 500,
        arrows: false,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
    }
    const review = this.state.reviews;

    return (
        <div className="review">
            <div className="review_block">
                <div className="reviewContainer">
                    <div className="reviewTitle">
                        <h1>Review</h1>
                    </div>
                    <Slider {...settings} ref={slider => this.slider = slider && slider['innerSlider']}>
                        {
                            review.map((review, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="reviewCard" id={i} key={i}>
                                        <div className="reviewTitleCard">
                                            <p>{review.title}</p>
                                            <div className="reviewBlock">
                                                <div className="reviewParameters">
                                                    <div className="reviewText">
                                                        <h6>{review.name}</h6>
                                                        <p>{review.position}</p>
                                                        <p>{review.companyName}</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <img className='companyImg' src={review.companyImg} alt=""/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </Slider>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}
``

Comment: It's a very strange case, why do you need it if you have a real scroll? Why do you need two scrolls?

Comment: @Azu I don't know, they said that the design is interesting

Comment: Can you please show the design to give us an idea what the goal is?

Comment: https://chulakov.ru/company

Comment: I see only one scroll there. It's not clear what you'd like to achieve. Please explain.

Comment: the slider should work when scrolling, when the slider is scrolling, then the page is also scrolled

Comment: side-scrolling should work too